# A log file which contains information like < timestamp , customer-id , page-id ,list of titles>

Tags: python, parsing

Write a code to print all the unique customers visited in last hour

My try:

```
import datetime

def find_repeated_customer():
     file_obj = open(" my file path","r")
     customer_last_visit = {}
     repeat_customer = set()

     while line in file_obj:
        timestamp,customer_id,page_id = line.split(" : ")
        last_visit = customer_last_vist.get(customer_id,None)

            if not last_visit:
                customer_last_visit[customer_id] = last_visit
            else:
        # assuming time stamp looks like 2016-10-29 01:03:26.947000
                year,month,date = timestamp.split(" ")[0].split("-")
                current_visit = datetime.date(year,month,date)

                day_diff = current_visit - last_visit

                 if day_diff >=1:
                    repeat_customer.add(customer_id)
                 customer_last_visit[customer_id] = current_visit
```

I am completely failing over in order to get my desired output. By doing this I am able to get repeated customers in last one day but how to get unique users?

Comment: We need the output and the input so far

Comment: Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this kind of manipulation in one pass. You have to pass once through lines to get customers, and only then You can check who came once. In another pass, You check if current customer is in list on once-customers and do something with him.